# mingw-get.exe: unrecognised option '-Wall' Code::blokcs

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw, codeblocks

So I am just trying to make a very simple program to test out my compiler. I "made" this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!");
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile it (Code::Blocks MinGW) I get these errors:

```
mingw-get.exe -Wall -O2 -Wextra -ansi -g  -c "C:\Users\Arshia\Desktop\Lab 4 Playground\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o
mingw-get.exe: unrecognised option `-Wall'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Any idea what I can do? All help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code::blocks can be tricky to configure. It seems your compiler switches have gotten messed up. I would try reinstalling code::blocks to revert to the default settings. One obvious problem is that mingw-get.exe is not a compiler, but is being tasked as one. [This page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/getting_started) may be of use to you.